# 24 - Trying to remember a specific character that Jack Bauer tortured

Tags: 24

Really hope someone can help with this as it's bugging me to death.

In one specific episode (no idea which season, sorry), either a captured enemy or a person of interest who I *think* was an arms dealer is brought in to CTU headquarters for questioning.

Typically Jack is impatient, and this quickly turns in to a bizarre torture scene (although I can't remember how) where the guy ends up dead on the floor of CTU, leading Jack using a couple of power cables to jump start the guy back to life. The power cables part is what I seem to remember the most.

I know that's a really sketchy outline of the plot, but I can barely remember it. If this sparks memory in anyone, can you tell me *who* this 'arms dealer' was that Jack was torturing?

Comment: I don't recall that scene/antagonist, sorry, but my favorite interrogation is when Jack "tortures" a guy with a popsicle by showing him a lit blow torch first and then running the frozen treat along his abdomen out of view.

Comment: I will have to bounty this question up, I'm desperate to know the answer and I won't get it unless I rewatch all of 24!

Comment: My favorite was in the 24 movie between seasons 7-8 where Jack straight up chokes his captor to death with his thighs while tied up! That's badass!

Comment: Are you sure it's not Graem Bauer, Jack's brother, in his house? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82ID04NKevc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a complete list of interrogation scenes in 24 [here](http://24.wikia.com/wiki/Interrogation). None of them seem to match your description exactly, but this seems reasonably close:

> **Paul Raines**: After CTU discovered Paul's name on the lease of the building where the terrorist attacks had been planned, Jack tortured him by electrocuting him with wires from a lamp, despite Paul's (truthful) insistence of innocence

Comment: That was in a hotel IIRC--definitely not at CTU--and in the presence of his ex-wife, now Jack's girlfriend. Also, Paul wasn't killed during that scene.

Comment: This isn't what I'm thinking of, but that excellent link is now making my doubt my own sanity/memory because none of those descriptions match what I was thinking of. I really am going to have to rewatch 24! Accepted answer though because it's the best approximation of what I was looking for.